# Open parent model with event_open_popup

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I've got two models : maintenance.intervention and maintenance.intervention.task

In model intervention, there's a One2many relation toward task.

When I display the tasks in calendar view and click on one of them, instead of opening a form view for the task model, I'd like to open the form view of parent intervention. (In edition mode if possible)

The field with the parent id is "intervention_id".

Q1 : Is it possible ?
Q2 : How to do it ?

The code below opens the correct view, but doesn't have the data needed.

```
    <record id="view_maintenance_intervention_tasks_calendar" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">maintenance.intervention.tasks.calendar</field>
        <field name="model">maintenance.intervention.task</field>
        <field eval="2" name="priority"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <calendar color="user_id" date_start="date_start" date_stop="date_end" string="Task" quick_add="False"
                      event_open_popup="%(module.views_maintenance_intervention_form)s">
                <field name="hour_to"/>
                <field name="technician"/>
                <field name="client_name"/>
                <field name="installation_zip"/>
                <field name="installation_city"/>
                <field name="intervention_type"/>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="intervention_code"/>
                <field name="intervention_id" invisible="1"/>
            </calendar>
        </field>
```